# User can login through API but not into Salesforce itself

Tags: api, profile, user

API Only is unchecked. When we use the PW for his API, it works, but when we try to login through our SF URL it just says password invalid.

Admins can login to him just fine.

Here is a screenshot of his User: [image]

Comment: what is PW? ...can you check if securitytoken needs to get login

Comment: PW stands for password.

Comment: What does login history show?

Comment: The profile assigned to that user has "API enabled" access. I think he will be able to logged in through API but not through UI.

Comment: API enabled does not prevent UI login.  API only user is what prevents UI login.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a special string was added to the API password to make it work; we had to remove that from the UI password.